# Counting the number of observations that meet certain criteria over time

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with information about an individual's household and region. Please see the example below:

[Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxsSu.jpg)

I would like to create a variable, exemplified in column F, that shows, for the current year, the number of former household members (as identified by hid in 2006) who stay in a different region.

To explain what I mean in more detail:

In 2006, column F is 0 because all individuals live in the same household, i.e. no one has any former household member living in a different region.

In 2007, pids 2 and 3 both move to new households, which causes everyone to have 2 former household members living in another region.

In 2008, pid 3 moves back to his original region, so now pids 1 and 3 have only one former household member (pid 2) living in a different region, while pid 2 has 2 such connections (pids 1 and 3).

How would I be able to do this in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

I divide your table into three. First one is to state the initial status ,second one is to check the current status and the third one is result table.

[image: screenshot]

For the last table I used `=SUMIF($D$8:$D$13;A17;$E$8:$E$13)`also without the need of third table you can use pivot table to get the same result.

I hope this solution is convenient for you.